# Poetic expression with an adjective

Tags: adjectives

If a dog is surrounded by happy people, can I express it as ‘a dog happy around itself’? I mean, is it technically possible even though this expression is very rarely used?

In my native language, if flowers are in the red bottle, we can call it as ‘red flower.’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You would describe it as "A dog that is surrounded by happy people".  Your expression is ungrammatical and (moreover) meaningless.

"Red flowers" or "Happy dog" describe the flowers or dog. They don't describe the vase or the people around the dog.

These are red flowers. These flowers are red.

They are not white flowers.

[image]

Comment: But James technically is it not against grammar?

Comment: Your expression is ungrammatical.  That means it is against grammar.

Comment: It sounds acceptable in Korean though

Comment: Interesting, but Korean is a very different language from English.

Comment: @JamesK - "Korean is a very different language from English". Indeed.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562597/exceptional-usage-of-an-adjective it’s solved!

Comment: @James K Your answer is worthy! I came to know a literal sense thanks to you!